# FieldConverter with ExcelStorage class

Tags: c#, filehelpers

I'm using FileHelpers Library 2.0 and reading data from excel file with class ExcelStorage.

I have those  classes

```
[DelimitedRecord("|")]
public sealed class ServicoOutro
{
    [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Both)]
    [FieldConverter(typeof(MyConverter))] 
    internal Int32 srv_tx_iva;
}

    public class MyConverter : ConverterBase
    {
        public override object StringToField(string from)
        {
            return Convert.ToString(from).Replace("%", "");
        }

        public override string FieldToString(object fieldValue)
        {
            string str = Convert.ToString(fieldValue);

            return str.Replace("%", "");
        }
    }
```

When a read data from excel file with:

```
ExcelStorage pvrOs = new ExcelStorage(typeof(ServicoOutro));
pvrOs.FileName = "fileName.xlsx";
pvrOs.StartRow = 2;
ServicoOutro[] resCc = (ServicoOutro[])pvrOs.ExtractRecords();
```

the methods of the MyConverter class are not called.

Can anyone help me.

Thanks

Comment: Try to get the latest 3.x

Answer (score 1):

Your `MyConverter` is not correct for a field of type Int32.

The `StringToField` override is used when importing. It returns a type `object` which must match the type of the destination field, which in your case is `Int32`.

The `FieldToString()` override is used when exporting. It is tells the engine how to format the `string` output when converting an `object` with value `fieldValue`. You can just ignore it.

Something like the following

```
public class MyConverter : ConverterBase
{
    public override object StringToField(string from)
    {
        // you might like to check for nulls first...
        string output = from.Replace("%", "");
        // return Int32 because srv_tx_iva is Int32
        return Convert.ToInt32(output); 
    }

    public override string FieldToString(object from)
    {
        return from.ToString();
    }
}
```